Next.js using Fabric.js - Resize object fit the canvas editor
I'm making a restaurant floor plan using fabric.js in next.js, I can make a floor plan like the following image picture, and I'm saving it as json.
then I want to render the results on a different page, and the result is that the object that has been created cannot adjust the size of the available canvas editor, as in this picture picture
what do I have to do? Does the editor's canvas size have to be the same everywhere it will be used? Or can the object and canvas be responsive?
